# Intellij14.1 Error:No main class for module

Tags: java, intellij-14

I have just try HelloWorld

```
public class hw {
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
    }
}
```

but, console said when I tried to compile:

```
Error:No main class for module: HelloWorldTest
Error:Compilation failed
```

I don't know I don't know what I have wrong, Why it give me this warn ?

Comment: the code you show us is for a class named "hw", you are talking about `HelloWorld` and the error message state `HelloWorldTest`, so you might want to clarify

Comment: 'HelooWorldTest' is a Project Name, and 'hw' is a Java class name.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file HelloWorld.java at the root of your source package:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
    }
}
```

Then from the project explorer (left pane), right click on your HelloWorld class, and select Run 'HelloWorld.main()'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Haxe plugin installed?
If so it's likely the source of the problem.

https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/435604?tstart=0 and https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/435708

Try the fix in the first link or uninstall the plugin.